# Flag on deleted answer still pending

Tags: bug, flags

I was just reviewing my [flag summary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/5596) when i came across this.
[image]

It seems like the answer and the user was deleted, (probably causing the flag to disappear from the review queue)

Link on the flag:[Valentine's Day version of Angry Birds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16224/valentines-day-version-of-angry-birds/16561#16561)

Looks like a bug to me ;)

Comment: Looks to me like the flag should have been processed, no idea why it hasn't been.